# Is there a Gmail API support for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gmail-api

I need to know if there is a Flutter support for Gmail API?

I've searched on the Gmail API webpage and looks like they don't have support for Flutter right now.

I'm asking it because I need to build an app like Gmail (I mean all functionality)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a mail using a click event then you can try

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'mailto:test_user@example.org?subject=test&body=hello';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Check the complete code [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher)

---

Or you can check GMail api [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis)